# clear timer - javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

im having a problem, I cant seem to stop the timer... in fact it speeds up!

```
var number = 0;
var timer;
function get_data( url ){
    number++;
    $('#requests').html( number );
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', url: './includes/ajaxGetData.php', data: 'url=' + encodeURIComponent(url), cache: false, timeout: 10000,
        error : function(){ 
            timer = window.setTimeout( get_data( url ), 2000 );
        },
        success: function(html){ 
            if( html.substr(0,12) == '<!-- die -->' ) {
                $("#result").html('<p>Complete...</p>' + html );
                $('#requests').html('');
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }else{
                $("#result").html(html);
                timer = window.setTimeout( get_data( url ), 2000 );
            }
        }                           
    });
}
get_data( 'http://example.com' );
```

can anyone see where im going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
timer = window.setTimeout( get_data( url ), 2000 );
```

This **calls `get_data`** and creates a timeout for **the result** of this call. Use something along these lines:

```
timer = window.setTimeout(function () { get_data(url) }, 2000);
```

Comment: i did think this and had your second line of code originally with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The speeding up comes from the setTimeout in the if else in your succes, which seems to be always else.

Try this for html comment selection

```
$(html).match(/<!--.*?-->/g));
```

or in your case

```
$(html).match(/<!-- die -->/g));
```

And think about what happens if you overwrite an already set Timer

```
timer = window.setTimeout( get_data( url ), 2000 );
```

clear it befor you set a new one, otherwise "the old" will fire

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = window.setTimeout( get_data( url ), 2000 );
```